# Index out of range error when selecting the second row of a datagridview in windows forms

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have seached and did all the experiments that can be done to solve this problem but nothing is working for me. I am trying to get the selected row of a from to a datatable. When I select the first row and click the link to parse the data to the datatable, it works fine but when I select the second row, I get the index out of range error. Below is my code,

```
private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            int rowindex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

            dt.Clear();
            dt.Columns.Add("CustomerId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Style", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("BookingId", typeof(string));


            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            dr["CustomerId"] = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[rowindex].Cells["CustomerId"].Value; //I get the error here
            dr["Style"] = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[rowindex].Cells["Style"].Value;
            dr["BookingId"] = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[rowindex].Cells["BookingId"].Value;

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            Form3 fr = new Form3(dt);
            fr.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

It is realy confusing. Please help

Comment: How many row is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RowIndex` that you get on `dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex` is actually row index of a `DataGridView`, not the index of [`SelectedRows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows(v=vs.110).aspx).

Modify your code as below.

```
dr["CustomerId"] = dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells["CustomerId"].Value; //I get the error here
dr["Style"] = dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells["Style"].Value;
dr["BookingId"] = dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells["BookingId"].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's really no need to retrieve Row index in this case. If all you need is the currently selected row, then your code should look like this...

```
var row = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];

dr["CustomerId"] = row.Cells["CustomerId"].Value; 

dr["Style"]      = row.Cells["Style"].Value;

dr["BookingId"]  = row.Cells["BookingId"].Value;
```

This goes without saying, but please check first to ensure that a row is in fact selected...

Also, if you would like to iterate through ALL selected rows, you can use...

```
foreach(var row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows){
    //execute behaviour here...
}
```